# Using autojump / z in combination with pushd popd

Tags: command-line, active-directory

[Autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump) or [z](https://github.com/rupa/z) let you move around in your filesystem by entering only a part of the entire path (e.g. `z foo` takes me to `/long/long/path/to/foo`).

I often want to jump to a path, do something, and get back. This is easily achieved by using `cd -`.

However, if I jump to the path, cd around a little, then want to "get back", `cd -` would no longer work.

It would also not work if I started in dir `a`, wanted to jump to `b`, then to `c`, then "back" (to `b`) and "back" (to `a`).

Having to remember the name of where I want to jump back to (so I can do `z a` instead of "jump back") is no fun.

`pushd` and `popd` are built exactly to help you navigate through a stack of directories. I was wondering, if I could integrate the partial matching behavior of `z` with `pushd` and `popd`?

There seems to be no command line option in `z` or autojump which would give the target directory instead of cd'ing to it, otherwise I'd try `pushd $(z ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this, but `z` has a `-e` option that echoes the best match instead of `cd`ing to it.

I'll give an example of how to use this in fish shell

```
> pushd (z -e ...)
```

You can also use fish abbreviations to abbreviate `ze` to `z -e`. I am not sure if there is a way to set an abbreviation to automatically expand to `pushd (z -e ...)` with your cursor behind the closing bracket.

Comment: I'll leave the answer un-accpeted as it does not include information for `autojump` and there might be more convenient ways to achieve this